# Is there a way I can use the AngularJs HashKey to update an item in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I figure it's a simple solution but can't seem to get this working.

I have an arrayList of objects which I run through an ng-repeat on the html.
On each row I add a button which calls a save to an api server. This returns an Id from the DB which I want to update in the array on the view. Though I can't seem to find a way to.

I can't use $index because I'm filtering the items which I show so $index doesn't match up to the array index.

Controller:

```
vm.developmentItems = [];
service.getItems().then(function (results) {
                vm.developmentItems = results;
            });

function saveItem(item) {
     service.updateOrCreate(item)
        .then(function (newId) {
               //Need to update the viewmodel here.
               //Tried sending in the $index but because I'm filtering the $index doesn't match the array.
                item.id = newId; //Tried this

            });
}
```

Html:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in vm.developmentItems | filter: {filter: cat.id}">
<td>{{item.name}}</td>
<td><button type="button" data-ng-click="vm.saveItem(item)"></button></td>
</tr>
```

So I thought well if I could update the item in the array based on trackin the hashtag and angular uses maybe I can do it that way. I could do an array foreach but was wondering if there was some quick way using angular since I had the hashtag.

Comment: I can't really tell what you're trying to accomplish.  If you update the array (the "model"), the view will automatically reflect your model, and thus the new ID.  Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is update the existing developmentItem with the newId, then I would just find the current item in the array and use that index to do the update.

```
vm.developmentItems = [];
service.getItems().then(function (results) {
                vm.developmentItems = results;
            });

function saveItem(item) {
     service.updateOrCreate(item)
        .then(function (newId) {
               //Need to update the viewmodel here.
               //Tried sending in the $index but because I'm filtering the $index doesn't match the array.
                var currentIndex = vm.developmentItems.indexOf(item);
                vm.developmentItems[currentIndex].id = newId;
            });
}
```

Comment: You know not sure why I didn't think of that. I've done it before, think it's the long hours starring at the screen :) Thank you!